# How to make elements stop popping out of div that I made?

Tags: html, out

I want to make a *box(in a form of div)* that could arrange and move around objects in.

But, when I try to make objects to alight to left they pop out of it.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Just wondering how your code might look like?

Comment: We need code! How are you trying to align them to the left? That could be your problem.

Comment: posted it below,first time posting here,sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
#slide
 {
 margin: 100px 100px;
 background:green;
 height:200px;
 width:100px;
 overflow: hidden;
 clear:both;
}
```

Try this(replace your class)

Answer (score 0):

Edited found the answer:
just add position:relative;
to #slide in css file

HTMl

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="slide">
        <div id="right">

        </div>
        <div id="left">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Css

```
   #slide
   {
   margin: 100px 100px;
   background:green;
   height:200px;
   width:100;
   }
   #right
   {
   top:40%;
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   background:black;
   right:0;
   position:absolute;
   }
   #left
   {
   top:40%;
   height:20px;
   width:20px;
   background:black;
   left:0;
   position:absolute;
   }
```